# How to reference nested classes with css?

Tags: html, css, class, inner-classes

When using CSS, how can I specify a nested class?

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box box-default">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Collapsable</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
      </div><!-- /.box-header -->
      <div class="box-body">
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span style=""> Phone : 0800 000 000</span></p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span style=""> Web : http://www.example.com</span></p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span style=""> Map : example map address</span></p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span style=""> Email : example@address.com</span></p>
      </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</div>
```

This `css` code works correctly for the all the `html` on the page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    i{width: 30px;}
</style>
```

How can I specify the `i` `class` in the `box1` `box-body` class?

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
<style type="text/css">
    box1 box-body i{width: 30px;}
</style>
```

Comment: You need to put a full-stop / period in your class statements `.box1 .box-body i{width: 30px;}`

Comment: Take a look at this great tutorial about selectors: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In CSS, `classes` are prefixed by a `.`, `ids` are prefixed by `#`, and elements are not prefixed at all.

This is how you need to declare your CSS:

```
.box1 .box-body i {
   width: 30px;
}
```

Note that `box1` and `box-body` are both classes, while `i` is an element.

---

**Example**:

```
<div class="class"></div>
<div id="id"></div>
<div></div>
```

I have listed three different `<div>` elements. This is how they would be accessed in CSS:

```
// first div
.class {
[some styling]
}

// second div
#id {
[some styling]
}

// third div
div {
[some styling]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The classes in your CSS need periods before them. Note `i` doesn't since it's an element not a class.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .box1 .box-body i{width: 30px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Selectors for classes in CSS need a ".":

```
.box1 .box-body i{/*your style*/}
```

Maybe you should take a look at this page:

[Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Answer (score 1):

```
   <style type="text/css">
   .box1 .box-body i{width: 30px;}
   </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to know how css selectors work. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) is brief description about css selectors.

In your case,

```
.box .box-body i{
  width:30px;
}
```

space between two selectors defines second element is child of first.
In your case, element i is child element of element which has box-body class. and that element is child element of class which has .box class.