# CSS Different Class

Tags: css, class

I need change a color for this element

```
<div class="box download">
    <div class="box-inner-block">
        <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Plugin Windows</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call a from CSS with:

```
.download.box-inner-block a {
    color: white!important;
}
```

But it does not work, why? I need this color only for the element in `.box-inner-block` inside `.download`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference nested classes with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505225/how-to-reference-nested-classes-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for as understood in your question ?

If so you need to carefully watch how you indent and construct your css.

As you can see in my snippet I added a space between:
`.download .box-inner-block a`
in order to make that work.

You can also remove `!important` from you css as it will not be useful in that case. If you need it, don't forget to add a space bewtween `white` and `!important`

```css
.download {
    background-color: black;
}

.download .box-inner-block a {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box download">
  <div class="box-inner-block">
    <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Plugin Windows</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, just add need a space from two class =)

Comment: Glad it helped, just remember to accept my answer if you find this helpful for others to get help too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong selector, as `.download.box-inner-block` selects elements which has both `download` AND `box-inner-block` classes.

```
<div class="download box-inner-block"/>
```

To target nested elements, leave a space between the two class selectors. So the correct selector in your case is:

```
.download .box-inner-block a {
    color: white;
}
```

In this case you can drop `!important` too.